# Can a $2D$ canonical transformation also be holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, canonical-transformation

In Hamiltonian mechanics we have canonical transformations on an even-dimensional space. What if we consider a canonical transformation of two variables $f(x,y)=u(x,y)\mathbf{e_1}+v(x,y)\mathbf{e_2}$ as a function on $\mathbb{C}$ and require that the transformation is also holomorphic?
What one gets by combining the Cauchy-Riemann equations with the symplectic condition $\{u,v\}=1$ is that
\begin{equation}
(\partial_xu)^2+(\partial_yu)^2=1
\end{equation}
and the same applies to $v$.

Question: What are some examples of a such function $f$?

I can think of a component e.g. $u$ as
\begin{equation}
u(x,y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{equation}
that satisfies the condition above but then Iam not anble to find a $v$ such that $f$ is holomorphic.
I tried with something as
\begin{equation}
u(x,y) = \sin\theta(x,y)\qquad v(x,y)=\cos\theta(x,y)
\end{equation}
but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what is your question. If I just look at the title, $u(x, y) = x$ seems to have the property you request (and similarly for $v$). I don't think this is what you'e looking for, though. If not I suggest you clarify what you want.

Comment: @lmsteffan You are right, I clarified.

Comment: You're effectively asking for holomorphic functions whose derivative $f'$ has unit norm. A holomorphic function of constant norm is constant. Since $f'$ must be constant, the only examples are rigid motions, $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z + b$ for some real $\theta$ and complex $b$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang could you please turn the comment into an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl; dr: Any such mapping is a holomorphic Euclidean motion, i.e., of the form $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z + b$ for some real $\theta$ and some complex $b$.

---

Let $(x, y)$ denote Cartesian coordinates in $D$, and write $z = x + iy$.

**Lemma** Let $D$ be a plane region (connected, non-empty open set). If $g$ is holomorphic in $D$ and $|g|^{2} = 1$ in $D$, then $g$ is constant.

*Proof*: Standard complex analysis exercise, see spoiler.

> Write $g = s + it$ with $s$ and $t$ real-valued. By hypothesis, $g$ is holomorphic and $|g|^{2} = s^{2} + t^{2} = 1$ in $D$. Differentiating with respect to $x$ and cancelling the factor of $2$ gives $ss_{x} + tt_{x} = 0$. Differentiating with respect to $y$, cancelling $2$, and using Cauchy-Riemann gives $ss_{y} + tt_{y} = -st_{x} + ts_{x} = 0$. Squaring these equations and adding gives, after a bit of algebra, $(s^{2} + t^{2})(s_{x}^{2} + t_{x}^{2}) = 0$. Since $s^{2} + t^{2} = 1$ and $s_{x}$, $t_{x}$ are real-valued, we deduce $s_{x} = t_{x} = s_{y} = t_{y} = 0$ in $D$. By the mean value theorem, $g$ is constant in $D$.

**Proposition**: Assume $u$ and $v$ are real-valued functions in a plane region $D$, and that $f = u + iv$ is both holomorphic and area-preserving in $D$. Then $f$ is affine, of the form $f(z) = e^{i\theta}x + b$ for some real $\theta$ and some complex $b$.

*Proof*: Because $f$ is holomorphic, the Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_{x} = v_{y}$ and $u_{y} = -v_{x}$ are satisfied in $D$. Because $f$ is area-preserving,
$$
1 = \det Df = u_{x}v_{y} - u_{y}v_{x} = (u_{x})^{2} + (u_{y})^{2} = |f'|^{2}.
$$
Since $f'$ itself is holomorphic, it is constant by the lemma. We therefore have $f'(z) = e^{i\theta}$ for some real $\theta$. The identity theorem implies that for some complex $b$, we have $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z + b$ in $D$.